# Django models -> what is the best approach to access 2 separated models

Tags: django, django-models

i am developing a small app for sharing . 
to reduce database hit i need a relationship between 2 models (Followers) and (Share)

these are my models

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user  = models.ForeignKey(User, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True , related_name="user_follower")


class Shared(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user  = models.ForeignKey(User, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True , related_name="user_shared")

class Profile(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    follow = models.ManyToManyField(Follow)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True,null=True , related_name="profile")

class Notes(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    shared = models.ManyToManyField(Shared)
```

now i wanna do something like this in my django view

```
def return_users_note_shared_with(request):
    followers = request.user.profile.follow.all()
    return render(request , 'note.html',{ 'followers':followers})
```

in note.html how can i check if this note has been share with other users .
i know there is some relationship required in models but i can not 
figure this out

Comment: `note.shared_set.exists()`

Comment: thanks but this is not what i am looking for . it's check if the note is shared .i wanna check it for every user that following the owner of note.
i come up with template tag . but it's not efficient

Comment: just like facebook invite button on the page showing invited friends and uninvited friends